# Using a MFT mounted lens on a full frame camera

Tags: lens, lens-mount, lens-adapter

A long time ago, I bought 4 Rokinon Cine DS lenses with the MFT mount for my Panasonic GH5. Link to one of them is below.

[https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B00MZCCDA6/](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00MZCCDA6)

However, since then, I have been interested in getting a full frame camera. Would I need to purchase an all new set of lenses for that? The lenses I bought are listed as full frame, but I am concerned that because I bought the MFT mount there won't be any way I can use these.

I have looked at a couple of retailers and thing like MFT-to-L Mount or MFT-to-Canon RF adapters don't seem to exist.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: These were indeed full frame lenses but because they have been fitted with a Micro Four Thirds mount, I bet they are no longer able to project a full frame image. Even if you could find an adapter, I think the image would be compromised by the smaller opening of the MFT mount.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Would I need to purchase an all new set of lenses for that?

Yes.

> The lenses I bought are listed as full frame, but I am concerned that because I bought the MFT mount there won't be any way I can use these.

That's a legitimate fear. Samyang/Rokinon does not make interchangeable mounts (except on the [Xeen cinema lenses](https://www.ducloslenses.com/products/xeen-mount-kit)), and the smaller throat of the MFT mount (44mm) will cause vignetting on, for example, the EOS R or Canon EF mounts, which have 54mm throats, if you can even find an adapter, which is highly unlikely because of the similar mount depths.

The flange distance (distance from the lens mount to the sensor where the lens has to be held to achieve full focus range to infinity) with MFT is 19.25mm. EOS R's is 20mm and Sony E's is 18mm. So no adapter will make it compatible with EOS R full focus range (you have to shave 0.75mm off the back of the MFT mount), and 1.25mm isn't thick enough to make an adapter ring for Sony E.

You have to exchange the MFT mount lens for one in the new mount you're moving to, despite the main formulation of the lens being full-frame capable.

It would have been better to say, purchase lenses in Canon EF mount and adapt for MFT use if you were planning on moving to full frame mirrorless in the future. But that's not much use to you at this point.

Comment: MFT is 19.25 and EOS-R is 20mm... means the MFT lens would have to be recessed 0.75mm into the EOS-R body. Sony E being 18mm means there's 1.25mm for an adapter. // Nikon F mount also has a 44mm throat, so that in itself doesn't necessarily mean there will be vignetting if the lens is adapted to full frame.

Comment: @xiota. Thanks. Yeah, had it backwards. I'll fix that. And you have a point with the throat diameter. It doesn't stop Nikon F from working on EOS, adapted. Hmmm.

Comment: "1.25mm isn't thick enough to make an adapter ring for Sony E" -- M42-EF adapters are about 1.4mm thick.  Also, on a popular auction site, I found adapters to convert MFT to NEX.  Don't know how durable they are or well they work.

Comment: The only way to *really* know if a lens-body combination works is to try it.  But commercially available adapters is a reasonable indication that *some* lenses with MFT mount do work to some extent.  (But I do agree that it's generally better to get an EF or F mount lens if the intent is to adapt to other mounts.)

Answer (score 4):

If you really want, **you can adapt your lenses to Sony E-mount and Nikon Z-series bodies.**  The problems that must be overcome when adapting lenses are:

- Sensor coverage (size of the [image circle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_circle)).  Since the optics of your lenses were originally designed to cover full frame, they should continue to do so despite being fitted with a mount that is associated with crop sensors.
- Lens settings (aperture, focus).  This is typically a problem with electronically controlled lenses.  Since most Rokinon lenses are controlled manually, this probably doesn't apply to your lenses.
- [Flange focal distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flange_focal_distance).  The camera you adapt your lenses to must have a shorter FFD than the lens to make room for the adapter.  The FFD of MFT is 19.25mm.  Sony E mount (18mm) and Nikon Z mount (16mm) are full-frame mounts with shorter FFD.
- Commercial availability of adapters (or ability and willingness to make your own).  Adapters to fit MFT lenses to Sony E mount (NEX) and Nikon Z mount are commercially available.  It may be helpful to search for the phrase "adapter ring".